# How can I use windows 10 MSVC2015 build win7 apps

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using windows 10 and visusal studio 2015. I want to compile a windows 7 compatable exe file. But I use default build setting. The .exe gives some functions wrong entry point error.

Comment: Under windows 7 run the exe, it shows: "The procedure entry point CreateEventExA could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll"